# Reading from HUGE database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using LINQ to access my database tables. Some of the tables might have (hundreds of thousands) of records.

Reading from the table using a statement like this:

```
var records = db.Logs;
```

will make the application very very slow. It will load all records at once.

I need to filter the result with more than a condition, like:

```
if (UserID != null)
{
    records = records.Where(r => r.User == UserID);
}

if (UserIP != null)
{
    records = records.Where(r => r.IP   == UserIP);
}
```

The problem is that my first read from the table will bring me all the records and will make the application very slow.

Is there any way to make conditions in the LINQ statement (if, switch) as we used to do with SQL Statements?

This is how old logic used to be created:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Log WHERE 1=1";
if (UserID != null)
{
    sql += " AND User = '" + UserID + "'";
}

if (UserIP != null)
{
    sql += " AND IP = '" + UserIP + "'";
}

sqlCmd.query(sql);
```

Comment: Are you running this query on its own thread and using a callback to get the result?

Comment: @Hamid, What ORM are you using? Entity Framework? LINQ-to-SQL? Both of these generate smart TSQL that looks like your "old logic", unless something is done to prevent it, such as coercion from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` or a `ToList()`.

Comment: @Hamid, if possible start the SQL Profiler so you can see what queries are actually run on the server. That will teach you a lot about LINQ, EF and will allow you to tune.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually an assignment like:

```
  var records = db.Logs;
```

does not execute the query immediatly. It only prepares a datastructure to be used later. The execution of the query only happens when the code needs the data, and any where clauses are integrated in the query, preventing it from returning the whole table.

It is perfectly possible to do stuff like this:

```
  var records = db.Logs;

  if (filter1) records = records.Where(r => r.Field1 == condition1);
  if (filter2) records = records.Where(r => r.Field2 == condition2);
```

This will end in executing one query, with a (kind of) dynamic where statement.

You should define the correct indexes however.

Comment: And once again we see: Don't blame your performance problems on one particular statement unless you have done measurements to verify this claim: `var records = db.Logs;` has been shown to be innocent.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are wrong. A call to db.Logs should be return an IQueryable - this means the the query will not be executed until the data needs to be retrieved. Such as the point you access a property of a Log class or if your convert the collection to a list .ToList()

Answer (score 2):

What is `db.Logs`? Isn't it an `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`? Normally in Linq2SQL queries are not executed until you call `.ToArray` or `.ToList`, so you can build the query tree first.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that my first read from the table will bring me all the records and will make the application very slow.

```
var records = db.Logs
```

does not read from the table. You haven't done anything except create a query (it's analogous to creating the SQL command text without sending the command text to the database for execution). Turn on the feature that lets you see the SQL commands being sent to the database and you will see that this line of code does not send anything to the database. In fact, neither does this line:

```
records = records.Where(r => r.User == UserID);
```

This is just modifying the query named `records` (you should really call it `recordsQuery`) to add a condition on `User`. It's not until you iterate over the query that it is actually sent to the database for execution. So either

```
records.ToList();
```

or

```
foreach(var record in records) {
    // something something
}
```

or many other ways of executing a query.

> This is how old logic used to be created:

I hope not. Hello injection attacks!

> Some of the tables might have (hundreds of thousands) of records.

Hundreds of thousands is NOTHING.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to using Paging, get your data do whatever you want and then get another page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Records> records;

if (UserID != null)
{
    records = db.Logs.Where(r => r.User == UserID).ToList();
}
else
{
    records = db.Logs.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, hundred of thousands of rows is far from huge.

Back on topic, if you are passing around an `IQueryable<T>` then the SQL will be executed every time it is enumerated. If you're old code is correct and your new code is slow, this is most likely your problem. You can avoid thus by calling `ToList()`, converting it to an `IEnumerable<T>` and putting all the data in memory.

Finally, you can page the data by calling `.Skip(PageSize * PageIndex).Take(PageSize)`.

Answer (score -1):

if you use lambda expression, the query will not execute until you use it, such as convert to list or enumerate all data.

```
var filtered = (from l in db.Logs
where l => l.User == UserID
select l).ToList();
```

Comment: please try before you speak, thanks. and if you really care about performance please do not use linq.